# Jquery validate, two rules, only one needs to be valid. Possible?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

On a login form I can accept a user id (number) or email address. These are respectively set by adding the attributes `data-rule-number` and `data-rule-email`, which will hook up the basic jQuery validate rules for these fields. However, I only need one of these to be valid. The user needs to enter either a number, or an email, and not anything else (i.e. `abc` would be invalid, but `123` and `a@b.com` would be fine).

I'll also be setting the `data-rule-required` attribute, which would make the field mandatory at all times.

Is this configuration possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this new method

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("numberandemail", function(value, element) {
    return jQuery.validator.methods['number'].call(this,value,element)
            ||jQuery.validator.methods['email'].call(this,value,element);
}, "Please enter a valid number or email ."
);
```